# Architecture MVVM questions about correct realisation

Tags: ios, mvvm

I saw different ways of using MVVM architecture in iOS and I have few questions about it:

**1** As "D" letter says in "SOLID" depend on abstractions not on exact types. But if I have simple viewController(VC) should I use this approach if I have simple VC with simple viewModel(VM) that initialised in viewDidLoad of the VC? Is that approach good in spite of boilerplate code I should write protocol to fulfil letter "D" in "SOLID"?

**2** If we look at rootViewController should we use dependency injection for our viewModel via property from appDelegate or it is ok to instantiate it inside viewDidLoad so there will be no dependency injection?

**3** Sometimes I see that delegation used for data binding but if I use Boxing instead is it better approach? (I know about reactive programming but I want to choose between this two)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't write a protocol if you're not going to reuse it. Look up some critical stuff about [protocol-oriented programming](http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/protocol-oriented-programming/).
2. It really does not matter where you get your viewmodel, you could also inject it in the constructor or get it in viewDidLoad.
3. I don't think there is a *better* there, but I don't do data binding that much.